# Google Maps doesnt appear in my app

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map to appear on my app and today I started working in a new computer and just ctrl+c, ctrl+v the code, the problem is that I cant get the map. Searching for something in the logcat I found this:

```
E/MDM﹕ [64] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
06-02 09:04:36.660    2827-5382/? D/GCM﹕ GcmService start Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.gcm.GcmService } com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE
06-02 09:04:36.675    2827-2827/? D/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Received GmsCore event: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.be.proximity.authorization.bt.AuthorizationBluetoothService$AutoStarter }.
06-02 09:04:36.675    2827-2827/? E/AuthorizationBluetoothService﹕ Proximity feature is not enabled.
06-02 09:04:36.695  32750-32750/? V/GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher﹕ Received broadcast intent Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.INITIALIZE flg=0x10 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.common.stats.GmsCoreStatsServiceLauncher }
06-02 09:04:36.745    2768-5383/? E/MDM﹕ [73] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}
```

Comment: Have you create a KEY from your account ? Have you define your SHA1 in your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: From here you can implement map step by step : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Comment: Yes, there was an existing key and now I just created a new one for the same package name, but it still not working. I will check this, thank you

Comment: Just fixed it, the problem was that the SHA1 certificate for the application changed when I changed my to my new computer, I just add the the new certificate to the same key and now it is working. Thanks for the help